# Using `texelFetch` to sample from a texture in a vertex shader: what colorspace should I expect?

Tags: glsl, webgl, webgl2

I'm using transform feedback and a vertex shader in my WebGL 2 program to perform calculations quickly and get the results. I'm providing images to my shader as textures (which will pretty much always be sRGB encoded ones). I'm finding that when I use `texelFetch` to do so, I get back results in the sRGB colorspace.

This is what I want, but I'd like to know the rule that governs it: can I always expect to get back the exact values my images were formatted in? I've read that sometimes shaders will convert the original colorspace to linear, which I *don't* want, and so want to avoid.